# Problem with WhenEvent

Tags: differential-equations, modeling, parametric-functions

I am trying to add a time dependent fraction to a parameter in `NDSolve`, 
i.e. when `10 < t< 20`, add `s` to `k1`...

```
Manipulate[ sol = NDSolve[{A'[t] == k1*A[t], A[0] == 10, 
                           WhenEvent[ 10 < t < 20, k1 -> (k1 + s)]},
                           A, {t, 0, 100}],
            {k1, 0.0, 1.0}, {s, 0.0, 1.0}]
```

But I cannot get the code to work, and get the following error message.
Does anyone have any suggestions, or can find the error in the code?

> ```
> NDSolve::wenset: Warning: the rule FE`k1$$16->FE`k1$$16+FE`s$$16 will not
> directly set the state because the left-hand side is not a list of state variables. >>
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use `WhenEvent` to do what you want.  The value of `k1` is passed in the DE in `NDSolve`, not the symbol.  `WhenEvent` has the attribute `HoldAll`, so that it deals with `k1` and `s` as `Symbols`.  Perhaps you could use `ParametricNDSolve` (see below).

Perhaps you want something like this?

```
kparam[t_?NumericQ, k1_, s_] := If[10 < t < 20, k1 + s, k1];
Manipulate[
 sol = NDSolve[{A'[t] == kparam[t, k1, s]*A[t], A[0] == 10}, A, {t, 0, 100}],
 {k1, 0.0, 1.0}, {s, 0.0, 1.0}]
```

The solution (for `k1 == 0.1`, `s == 0.2`) looks like this:

```
Plot[Evaluate[A[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 30}]
```

[image: Plot of a solution]

This accomplishes the same thing with `ParametricNDSolve` (if you have v9.0.1):

```
psol = ParametricNDSolve[{A'[t] == k1*A[t], A[0] == 10, 
   WhenEvent[t < 10, k1 -> (k1 + s)], 
   WhenEvent[t < 20, k1 -> (k1 - s)]}, 
  A, {t, 0, 100}, {k1 \[Element] Reals, s \[Element] Reals}];

Plot[Evaluate[A[0.1, 0.2][t] /. psol], {t, 0, 30}]
  (* output same as above *)
```

Comment: Thanks, all solutions are great!

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to extend the solution offered by Michael E2:

```
psol = ParametricNDSolve[{A'[t] == k1*A[t], A[0] == 10, 
    WhenEvent[t < 10, k1 -> (k1 + s)], 
    WhenEvent[t < 20, k1 -> (k1 - s)]}, 
   A, {t, 0, 100}, {k1 \[Element] Reals, s \[Element] Reals}];
(*Plot[Evaluate[A[0.1, 0.2][t] /. psol], {t, 0, 30}]*)
```

Note that even in the case the DE has two `WhenEvent`s one can find the *sensitivity* of k1:

```
Plot[Evaluate[(A[0.1, 0.2][t] + {0, .1, -.1} D[A[k1, 0.2], k1][t] /. 
     k1 -> 0.1) /. psol], {t, 0, 30}, Filling -> {2 -> {3}}]
```

That's pretty cool!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `WhenEvent[]` for this:

```
Manipulate[Plot[(A/. NDSolve[{A'[t] == (k1 + s HeavisidePi[1/10 (t - 15)]) A[t], A[0] == 10},
                              A, {t, 0, 100}] [[1]] )[x], {x, 0, 30}], 
{k1, 0.0, 1.0}, {s, 0.0, 1.0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `WhenEvent` here as stated. You can use it though but you have to treat *k* as a function of *t*, that is a discrete state variable `k[t]`.

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{
   sol = NDSolveValue[{
      y'[t] == k[t] y[t],
      y[0] == 10, k[0] == k0,
      WhenEvent[t > 10, k[t] -> k[t] + s],
      WhenEvent[t < 20, k[t] -> k[t] - s]
      }, y, {t, 0, 100},
     DiscreteVariables -> k]},
  Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 30}]],
 {{k0, .1}, 0, 1}, {{s, .2}, 0, 1}]

(* similar output *)
```